# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route" not found in

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-10

I am new to this world, but I have not been able to advance for a long time since I get this error when I start the server (excuse my level of English)

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route" not found in C:\laragon\www\nuevaApp\routes\web.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\nuevaApp\routes\web.php on line 7.

since I have these 'uses' at the beginning

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Could you help me? I do not know what else to do

I have gone so far as to reinstall these programs as well as install them on other PCs hoping to be able to see the website but I get the same error, with an unmodified project, it is the one created by Laragon

Comment: did you use the command "composer install"??